# Repeating a result on a line on the rows/lines below untill that result changes?

Tags: crystal-reports, repeat

[Image showing problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZfox.gif)

I want to know if there is a way of repeating the result of a column downwards until the change of result.

Attached image shows the problem.

I need 9.1stWC column to fill the number(which is actually a string) all the way down until that number changes.

The column is not null where the blank fields are (9.is null, shows this) so I'm going to have to write additional formulas to show I'm guessing.

I've used previous function but that only shows for the next line down then is blank after.
The replicate string function will go across the column not downwards.
I've looked at a stringVar but cant find a way of making this work on this report.
I'm reserved about grouping as I have a lot of other filters and by grouping I could possibly loose the sequence depending on what I group by.

My aim is to show WC which are equal to the current op line by doing a simple formula after I have managed to populate that column

Comment: It is difficult to understand the view you want. Please edit and show the outcomes in a proper format?

Comment: @JulyOrdinary I’ve just added a screen shot of my problem and updated the problem to be a little clearer (I hope). Thanks for the feed back

Comment: Try one thing, make a formula field and update its value when new value comes, and put that field in place of this database field in 9.1. You know the logic you want, just add that logic in formula.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume your column is a field named {Result.WC}.

Try this:

1. Create a formula. Let's call it @LastWC.
2. Use this code in the formula:

> ```
> shared stringvar sharedLastWC;
> if not isnull({Result.WC}) and {Result.WC} <> "" then sharedLastWC := {Result.WC};
> sharedLastWC; //returns
> ```

3. Replace the field by the formula.

The idea behind this is to set the shared variable when the field is not blank and not null. So, the variable will hold the last "filled" value.

I can't make a test with the purposed solution right now, but give it a try and make adjusts if you need. Tell me if it does not work.

If the first row can be empty, you may need to create an aditional formula do start the value of the shared variable in the header of the report.